# Print out types of data frame columns in Spark

Tags: pyspark

I tried using VectorAssembler on my Spark Data Frame and it complained that it didn't support the StringType type. My Data Frame has 2126 columns.

What's the programmatic way to print out all the column types?

Answer (score 34):

`df.printSchema()`  will print you the dataframe schema in an easy to follow formatting

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'printSchema'`

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
>>> for name, dtype in df.dtypes:
...     print(name, dtype)
```

or

```
>>> df.schema
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'schema'`